# Java: caching collections

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, design-patterns

Lets support we develop application in java and have a big table. And in order to increase performance we want to cache data. And here we have two ways of caching:

1. object cache - by id.
2. collection cache - caching collection of ids(!)

Example of collection cache. We have a sql query `SELECT * FROM person WHERE birhddate=A AND age<B ORDER BY firstName,lastName`. And for this query we cache collection of ids. Now, for the same query we can use cache. However, the problem of such caching is that if there is any updates/creates/deletes all collections caches become old and can't be used any more.

These are questions -

1. is collection cache used in practice?
2. are there any patterns/solutions/lib for java/algorithms to work with collection caches?

Comment: @Chris Martin Thank you for your time. I use guava cache. However, as I know it uses only key value cache.

Comment: Caching the ids may result in an expensive `IN` clause. That can be reduced by using a remote cache (memcached, redis) where a multi-get is very efficient. A materialized view at the database level may also provide a significant speedup.

Comment: Let's suppose … it had been worthwhile explicating what a `table` is, and what `big` _means_ (neither your question nor your tags mention RDB or some such (you _do_ mention CUD, if without the R)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem itself it does not matter whether you cache IDs in a collection or object contents in a collection.

If an object is updated, it may not fulfill the query criteria any more.

So what we speak about is **caching a query result**, correct?

Conceptually there are many approaches:

- Invalidate / clear the whole cache when an update happens
- Invalidate the query results whenever a table is updated
- When a value is updated: Evaluate the query against the old and new object value and update the cached result
- Don't tackle the problem at all and use an expire the data after let's say 5 minutes

The easiest options are clear the whole cache or work with an expiry. This works pretty well most of the time. Always start with the easy thing and then go for more complex solutions if this is really needed.

BTW: Within elastic search they implemented exactly the functionality you described, this is called "percolator". See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know whether or not your cached data is 'out of date' is by fetching the data again, thus negating the advantages of using a cache in the first place.

An alternative is to use an arbitrary time-out value after which the local cache will be tossed away and replaced with fresh data, so that your class implementing the caching (or 'Proxy' Design Pattern) will automatically fetch fresh data whenever it notices the cached data is stale.

To contemplate on that alternative, you can put some effort into finding the most optimal value, which should be the best tradeoff between expected time a record will have changed, and the longest time you can go without refreshing the data, maximising the profit you get from caching.